# Stream m3u8 to mp4 with Sound

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have a video URL that ends with the `m3u8` extension. I am trying to use VLC Media Player to stream this video to an MP4 file, but I am having an issue with the stream downloading only the video without the audio. Why is this happening and how can I resolve this issue? I am trying to output to an MP4 file, but if necessary, I can use a different file type as well so long as the video and audio remain high quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) is a container. The audio may be encoded with different codecs. Make sure you choose one that is supported. When you choose to stream with VLC, there are different profiles you can use. Try with different audio codecs and keep in mind that quality depends on codec type (lossy/lossless) and settings (bitrate etc.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have resolved the issue by selecting the option to save the video and audio exactly as it is streamed from the source.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the m3u8 format to mp4 by renaming the downloaded m3u8 file. It should play in VLC then.

Answer (score -1):

use ''vovsoft m3u8 downloader''  best and free, just paste m3u8 link and download

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1136577)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.